# Update all post that is not in another table

Tags: mysql

I have this tow table :-

```
an_post

ID   Name   Body   Pic   DateCreate
```

And the table 2 is :-

```
an_taxonomy

PostId   TaxId
```

We must all record in `table 1` have an record in `table` 2, That vale is `( "10" , "1" )`.

Where `10` is `PostId`, And `1` is `TaxID`.

How can insert into `table 2` all post from `table 1` by value `( "post_id" , "1")`, And not added before.

It must by not duplicated record in `table 2`

Answer (score 0):

If PostId is a unique index on the an_taxonomy table then merely do

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO an_taxonomy (PostId, TaxId)
SELECT ID, 1
FROM an_post
```

If not then you should check if the row already exists. Something like this:-

```
INSERT INTO an_taxonomy (PostId, TaxId)
SELECT a.ID, 1
FROM an_post a
LEFT OUTER JOIN an_taxonomy b
ON a.ID = b.PostId
AND b,TaxId = 1
WHERE b.PostId IS NULL
```

Comment: I test it and its make duplicate, there are now all posts have 2 tax, It must one tax

Comment: Can you post the actual table declares and some test data please that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I post the structure of table :)

Comment: Can you please post the structure (actual table declares, including indexes, etc) and some test data. And also which of the above 2 suggestions allowed duplicates?